# Location of external resource (JS) in spring mvc app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am using Maven, Spring, and Eclipse to deploy a tomcat v7 webapp. My directory structure looks like the following:

```
- src
- test
- war
  -- META-INF
  -- WEB-INF
    --- classes
    --- jsp
    --- script
      ---- base.js
    --- web.xml
    --- myapp-servlet.xml
```

My web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and myapp.servlet.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <!-- the application context definition for the myapp DispatcherServlet -->
  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>        
  </bean>

  <bean id="manager" class="com.myco.myapp.service.SimpleProductManager">
        <property name="product">
            <list>
                <ref bean="aModel"/>
            </list>
        </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="aModel" class="com.myco.myapp.domain.Product">
      <property name="name" value="example"/>
      <property name="id" value="1"/>
  </bean>
  <bean name="/list.htm" class="com.myco.myapp.LibraryController">
    <property name="manager" ref="manager"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
       <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

The actual JSP page, served by my controller, is getting dished out fine.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the resources (specifically the base.js file) to be put on the server. Or, probably more accurately, I think it's being *put* on the server, I just can't seem to access it. I've tried adding a `<mvc:resources>` tag, like this one: `<mvc:resources mapping="/script/**" location="/script/"/>` to my myapp-servlet.xml page, just under the `<beans...` declaration, but with no joy.

I have a link on my main page that is something along the lines of: `<a href="<c:url value='/script/base.js'/>">Script</a>`, but when I click it, it gives me an Apache Tomcat 404 error, stating that the resource is not available. (Strangely enough, it used to give the path I was trying to reach, namely /script/base.js, but it no longer does that... I'm not sure if that's a clue that I'm getting closer, or a red herring).

One thing to note - I've changed my tomcat configuration so that the module myapp is loaded with a root of '/' - meaning that I don't have to put the module name before the page (e.g. 'localhost:8080/hello.htm', instead of 'localhost:8080/myapp/hello.htm')

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out what was going on. I needed to do two things:

1. Move the script/ directory so that it was a direct subdirectory of
   war/
2. Right click on the project in Eclipse, select *Properties,*
   then click on *Deployment Assembly*. In this section, I added the
   war/script to the deployment assembly.

I am now able to access the javascript files.

Comment: It is because WEB-INF is a private area of the web app. It is only accessible for the application code (java classes e.g. servlets)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try configuring the resource mapping like this:

```
   <mvc:resources mapping="/script/**" location="/, classpath:/WEB-INF/script/" />
```

And avoid having to move your scripts.